# How to manually fire multiple queries in Apollo-client?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I am trying to manually fire multiple queries, similarly to `refetchQueries` that is available after a mutation.

```
this.props.client.query(
      {
        query: getPlacesForDateQuery
      },
      {
        query: getTimesQuery
      }
    )
```

This works only for the 1st query and it ignores the others. I am wondering if there is a way to do it, other than manually firing each query separately and waiting for it to complete.

Note: I don't know if it matters, but I am not using the new `Query` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this helpful article](https://blog.apollographql.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862)

I think your syntax is slightly off. You can compose multiple queries into one. This is your mistake here. Try it like so:

```
query ___composed {
  author {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
  fortuneCookie
}
```

or you can write two queries like so:

```
query firstQuery {
   author {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
query secondQuery {
  fortuneCookie
}
```

Comment: ok I ended up creating a new query that combines 2 existing ones (like your first code snippet). Thanks!